# Parallel Jenkins Pipeline causing unexpected behavior

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am very new to Jenkins automation so please bear with me.

I understand the concept of the intuitive declarative pipeline structure to write a Jenkinsfile but I am experiencing a very counter-intuitive behaviour.

I have a 2 parallel steps (pseudo-code) as

**Main file:**

```
file1 = load "./file1.groovy"

stage ('First-step') {
    steps {
        parallel (
            queue1: {
                script {
                    file1.step1(arg1_1, arg1_2)
                }
            }
            queue2: {
                script {
                    file1.step1(arg2_1, arg2_2)
                }
            }
        )
    }
    
}
```

**file1.groovy**

```
def step1 (arg1, arg2) {

    (result, option) = calculate(arg1, arg2)
    sh "python ${result1} --${option}"

}

def calculate (arg1, arg2) {
    def option= ""
    def result = ""
    
    if arg1 in <SOMETHING>
       option= <SOMETHING>
       result= <SOMETHING>
    ....
    
    
    return [result, option]
}
```

I need calculate as a separate function because this will be used in other functions defined within the file. Now I am noticing that, both result and options retrieved, in both the queue, to make the command in step1 is of queue2. My initial understanding was that there will be stack created for every instance of this function/method. But something else is happening.

It is probably my lack of understanding of groovy. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: what is the purpose of ´file2.step1(arg2_1, arg2_2)´ ? you do not have ´file2.groovy´

Comment: I apologise, that was a typo. I have fixed it.